# Why is my program not checking data in rows other than the first one in MySQL through Java?

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc

---

**Info:**

---

MySQL Workbench 8.0 CE

Eclipse IDE for JAVA developers 2020-03

Database name: database

Table name: data

---

I am trying to make a Java program that would connect to a MySQL database and act as a login form. There is an issue that the program is able to validate only the first or the last rows at random and cannot validate the rows in between them. There are 4 rows in total for the beginning. Here is my code:

The Connection conn is declared in the constructor and gets the connection through another class which returns it.

```
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    try
    {
        Statement st=conn.createStatement();
        ResultSet rs=st.executeQuery("select * from data");
        while(rs.next())
        {
            String usnm=rs.getString("username");
            String pswd=rs.getString("password");
            String mo=rs.getString("ph.no.");
            if(usnmf.getText().equals(usnm)&&pswdf.getText().equals(pswd))
            {
                flag=1;
                break;
            }
            if(usnmf.getText().equals(mo)&&pswdf.getText().equals(pswd))
            {
                flag=2;
                break;
            }
            if(!usnmf.getText().equals(usnm)&&!pswdf.getText().equals(pswd)||!usnmf.getText().equals(mo)&&!pswdf.getText().equals(pswd))
            {
                flag=0;
                break;
            }
        }


    }
    catch(Exception ex)
    {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Error :"+ex);
    }
    if(flag==1)
    {
        try
        {
            PreparedStatement pst=conn.prepareStatement(sql1);
            pst.setString(1, usnmf.getText());

            ResultSet rs=pst.executeQuery();

            if(rs.next())
            {
                name=rs.getString("name");
            }
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Login Successful... Welcome "+name);
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Error: "+ex);
        }

    }
    else if(flag==2)
    {

    }
    else if(flag==0)
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Invalid Login Info.");
```

Here the usnmf and pswdf are textfields of username and password respectively. The username field is expected to act as a field for both usernames and phone numbers which are in separate columns. Impractically the phone number field's data type is varchar and the password is being checked without hashing. This is just for the beginning. But when I enter **correct** data for any field the program shows invalid login info unless the data belongs to the first or the last row. Unluckily that too is at random. Sometimes, only the first row data is shown correct and sometimes, only the last row's.

Is there a bug in my code? Kindly help me out because after a thorough rechecking again and again, I am very frustrated.

Comment: the break keyword terminates the loop. what else did you expect? just use if else if instead of break there.

Comment: @Stultuske Will while loop with no break work?

Comment: why wouldn't it?

Comment: You're doing this wrong. You don't need to fetch the entire table. You should be using a WHERE clause matching the username and the password, and seeing if you get any matching rows. You should get one or zero. Let the database do the work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry for the grave stupidity but the solution was just to remove the **break** form where the not(!) condition was used. If the program didn't find a match in the first row, then the loop was broken and an invalid info message was shown.